# "Es lässt sich gut streiten über etw."

Tags: meaning

Im Allgemeinen bedeutet die Wendung, so OpenThesaurus, Folgendes:

> diskussionswürdig · diskutabel · (darüber) lässt sich streiten ·
>   (darüber) ließe sich reden

Welche Rolle spielt aber das Adverb "gut" in der Wendung?

Comment: "Gut" ist in diesem Satz kein Adjektiv, sondern ein Adverb.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Das "gut" bekräftigt hier, dass das Thema (besonders) gut geeignet ist, um darüber einen Streit oder eine Diskussion zu führen. Je kontroverser ein Thema bzw. je mehr subjektive und nicht miteinander vereinbare Meinungen es zu einem Thema gibt, desto "besser lässt sich darüber streiten".

Zum Beispiel ist der persönliche Filmgeschmack ein Thema, über "das sich gut streiten" lässt, weil es sehr subjektiv und oft kontrovers ist. Der Streit oder die Diskussion selbst muss deshalb aber noch nicht "gut" im Sinne von "ergebnisreich" sein – oft sogar im Gegenteil.

Comment: Da warst du wohl schneller als ich. Aber völlig richtig ;)

Comment: Noch etwas subtiler kann man aus "es lässt sich gut darüber streiten" manchmal herauslesen, dass der Streit zwar subjektiv und eher ergebnislos, aber nicht besonders ernst sein wird.

Comment: Implizit bist du drauf eingegangen, aber: Der "Streit" ist dann nicht etwa ein "ordentlicher" - der Austausch von objektiven Argumenten für und wieder mit der Hoffnung auf eine Einigung, sondern eher einer "um des Kaisers Bart" mit dem Austausch größtenteils subjektiver Nicht-Argumente und dem bestmöglichen Ausgang "agree to disagree".